# How to install odoo in docker?

Tags: docker, odoo-8

I just installed odoo 8 in docker container with this command.

```
$ docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_DB=mydb --name erp postgres:10
$ docker run -p 8088:8088 --name isp --link db:isp -t odoo:8
```

After running ,got the following output in terminal.

```
Unable to find image 'odoo:8' locally
8: Pulling from library/odoo
85b1f47fba49: Pull complete 
588cb84c434c: Pull complete 
b1262c37859c: Pull complete 
6f53189d2266: Pull complete 
70f9d845b031: Pull complete 
a207ac7158c3: Pull complete 
e76e3848d7b2: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:d1b8572fa50a6041779c0ee7e4b6c4152d1ffae1d10d8690b73c7acdbfa03bfc
Status: Downloaded newer image for odoo:8
2020-03-18 09:54:35,805 1 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0-20170815
2020-03-18 09:54:35,805 1 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/var/lib/odoo/addons/8.0', 
u'/mnt/extra-addons', u'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons']
2020-03-18 09:54:35,805 1 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: db
2020-03-18 09:54:35,805 1 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2020-03-18 09:54:35,805 1 INFO ? openerp: database user: odoo
2020-03-18 09:54:36,112 1 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Watching addons folder 
/var/lib/odoo/addons/8.0
2020-03-18 09:54:36,113 1 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Watching addons folder /mnt/extra- 
addons
2020-03-18 09:54:36,113 1 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Watching addons folder 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons
2020-03-18 09:54:36,512 1 INFO ? openerp.service.server: AutoReload watcher running
2020-03-18 09:54:36,512 1 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 
0.0.0.0:8069
```

What I am not clear is
1. Do I need to add my version 8 base code in those addon-path

```
addons paths: ['/var/lib/odoo/addons/8.0', 
u'/mnt/extra-addons', u'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons']
```

2. How can I add extra customize module?
3. Do I need to add docker master files?

Answer (score 0):

Same as when you migrate the port number with `-p` ,  run command with the option volume `-v`.

```
docker run -v "link to your customized module":/mnt/extra-addons -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo
```